# Track all modifications to a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, audit, change-tracking

We have a table which has only roughly 500 rows, but it is very important for us.

I want see all changes which happen to this table. The changes should get tracked with a timestamp.

I don't want the tracking to happen in the application code, since I want to track changes which happen via `psql` shell, too.

I am happy with a PostgreSQL specific solution, since I don't use a different DB in this context.

Answer (score 27):

*<sub>Answer compiled from comments</sub>*

You would put [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) for any DML event on the table that write information about the event to a log table. If you want to track DDL too, have a look at [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) - [sticky bit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/149341/sticky-bit).

Some example implementations given by [a-horse-with-no-name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name):

- [Tracking changes in PostgreSQL](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/) by Hans-Jürgen Schönig
- [Impossibly Lean Audit System for Postgres with hstore](http://cjauvin.blogspot.com/2013/05/impossibly-lean-audit-system-for.html)
- [Copying Pavel Stehule’s simple history table but with the jsonb type](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/) by Glyn Astill
- [Audit trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) in the PostgreSQL Wiki

Even if they are several years old, the basic idea hasn't changed and all of them are valid choices. The source for the fourth alternative has been updated recently: https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger

Comment: Very helpful links. Just be aware that if you try the suggested tricks using the `-` operator to get only changed columns, make sure you log the PK too otherwise you might not be able to identify the row!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to create generic triggers, from [Tracking changes in PostgreSQL](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/) by Hans-Jürgen Schönig and comments on that blog post.

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA logging;

CREATE TABLE logging.t_history (
        id              serial,
        tstamp          timestamp       DEFAULT now(),
        schemaname      text,
        tabname         text,
        operation       text,
        who             text            DEFAULT current_user,
        new_val         jsonb,
        old_val         jsonb
);

CREATE FUNCTION logging.change_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO logging.t_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val, old_val)
VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, pg_catalog.row_to_json(NEW), pg_catalog.row_to_json(OLD));
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER
SET search_path = pg_catalog,pg_temp;

CREATE TRIGGER audit_important_table
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON important_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE logging.change_trigger();
```

Note that the trigger is marked `SECURITY DEFINER` which is the moral equivalent of a setuid binary; see [Writing
SECURITY DEFINER
Functions Safely](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) and [Abusing SECURITY DEFINER functions in PostgreSQL](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/).

Answer (score 0):

A trigger-based approach, as many have mentioned, is the most straightforward solution that should just work fine for 500 rows with infrequent updates.

If you need a more sophisticated and scalable solution, you can use the [Change Data Capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) (CDC) pattern by connecting to a PostgreSQL replication log (WAL), reading all changes like a read replica, and storing them in a structured format. There are many open-source projects such as [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) that are often used to implement CDC.

Here are the main advantages of CDC over triggers:

- No performance overhead. No need to insert additional records on every `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `TRUNCATE` command.
- Flexibility and scalability. High volumes of data changes can be stored in a separate storage, not just in the original PostgreSQL database.
- Separation of concerns. No need to manage lots of triggers, which can become cumbersome with many trackable schemas and tables.

The main disadvantage of CDC is its complexity. Setting up and managing such a system can be challenging. You can check out https://github.com/BemiHQ/bemi which integrates Debezium with PostgreSQL for data change tracking at scale (I'm the author).

Answer (score -2):

An opensource module was created to solve this problem:
https://github.com/i-Cell-Mobilsoft-Open-Source/postgres_ddl_change_tracker

Comment: Hi Csaba. 1) If its yours, you need to state that.  2) the answer needs more info such as screenshot or help page

Comment: The above question is about tracking all changes to the table. The link you provided points to a projects which tracks DDL changes. This means this projects tracks changes in the table schema (like new columns). AFAIK  it does not track changes to rows.