# Is it possible to use the log of tracking changes to revert a table to a previous state in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

This thread ([Track all modifications to a PostgreSQL table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233735/track-all-modifications-to-a-postgresql-table)) discussed how to generate a log to track changes in PostgreSQL.

How to use the log to revert a table to its older version programmatically?

Comment: Yes, why not? As long as you record the required information (`OLD`).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Is there any example or tutorial about that? Thank you!